# Android continuous running service

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I am trying to do simple chat application using android.

1. Like whatapp, I want to run background service continuously whether activity is running or not running.

2.When I get message, then there should be notification.

1. Once clicked on notification, activity will be opened.

Using which API, I can do above all those things?

Comment: Look up. Before the first sentenced in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find details, specs and examples here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Be advised that the services running all the time drains the battery, so ideally you want a mixed solution with [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), if you're communicating with the server to receive messages.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) ... 
I did a little application that lunches a notification from a service . it is free without license ... you can find it [here](https://github.com/Ahmedfir/StartStopNotificationService.git) .
good luck